UX for multiple buttons
What is the best way of handling these buttons? we have almost 8 actions at the top of a table.


What Bobby and Mike mentioned as answers sounds like the right direction to me too. But I think there could be a better specific solution (from them, or me, or anyone else) if you could mention what the 6 buttons are for. Thanks!

Try surfacing top actions, and add the others to an overflow.
Think about scale:
If you have 3 actions, assume in the future you may have more. In your case you have 8.
If you have research, or your product team has specific aims for which actions are most important, or most prevalent, you can try the overflow pattern. Here's an example with an icon, and another using a dropdown:

You'll emphasize the 2 most important actions, and the overflow or 'more' icon allows a dropdown with additional actions.

I'd recommend limiting the number of actions or exposing actions once they are relevant. In this case, show the 'add' action, and once a user select an item from the list, expose the 'Delete', 'restock', 'revoke', etc... I'd recommend looking at the overflow suggestion above if you have several actions, or showing buttons only when they are available to the user.

Welcome to the site! I actually wouldn't recommend to hide actions which require a table selection, because that might lead users to the impression that they need to search elsewhere for the action. If only a selection is required, toggle the button inactive/active.

Thanks for the welcome and response. I believe the question is prioritization.  Do you fill the ui with every action. Or is there an option to use interaction to add friction ( for destructive actions). In a list/table view with 8 actions, it may be overwhelming to users to show all options. It’s pretty common to hide destructive actions until you have an item to delete/destroy

In case you're worried about too many buttons cluttering the UI, I would recommend to add an overflow mechanism (usually a menu button) to hide the less frequently used ones (which are shown in the menu as inactive, so user know they found the correct place, only some additional condition such as table selection is required).
